# How to format strings using values from other column in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, string-formatting

I need to do some string formatting using values from other column which separated by commas. Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
words <- c('%s + %s equal %s', '%s + %s equal %s')
arguments <- c('1,1,2', '2,2,4')
df <- data.frame(words, arguments)
df
             words    arguments
1 %s + %s equal %s        1,1,2
2 %s + %s equal %s        2,2,4
```

And I need a result like this:

```
             words    arguments         combined
1 %s + %s equal %s        1,1,2    1 + 1 equal 2
2 %s + %s equal %s        2,2,4    2 + 2 equal 4
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Spacedman corretly pointed out, the previous solution wasn't working anymore. It is also correct eval-parse solutions should be avoided when possible. Thanks @dash2: you make a good point.

So here follows a new tidyverse and R-base solutions.

---

### With `tidyverse`

Specifically: `dplyr`, `purrr`, `stringr`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(
    # split arguments by comma
    arguments = str_split(arguments, ","),

    # loop over words and arguments and call sprintf via do.call
    combind = map2_chr(words, arguments, 
                       \(...) do.call("sprintf", as.list(c(...)))))

#>              words arguments       combind
#> 1 %s + %s equal %s   1, 1, 2 1 + 1 equal 2
#> 2 %s + %s equal %s   2, 2, 4 2 + 2 equal 4
```

Note that the second argument of `do.call` has to be a list of arguments for the called function (in this case `sprintf`). That's why each item of `words` is combined (`c`) with each item of `arguments`, then forced into a list (`as.list`).

---

### With Base R

```r
df$combind <- mapply(\(...) do.call("sprintf", as.list(c(...))), 
                     df$words, strsplit(df$arguments, ","))

df

#>              words arguments       combind
#> 1 %s + %s equal %s   1, 1, 2 1 + 1 equal 2
#> 2 %s + %s equal %s   2, 2, 4 2 + 2 equal 4
```

Let's see the solution step by step:

```r
# loop simultaneously over the two columns of df via mapply
# (to see the solution step by step SIMPLIFY is set to FALSE)
mapply(c, df$words, strsplit(df$arguments, ","), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) |>
 
  # now set each vector to a list (to use do.call)
  lapply(as.list) |> 

  # call sprintf via do.call
  # (sapply is being used over lapply to force the simplicification of the list into a character vector)
  sapply(do.call, what = "sprintf")

#> %s + %s equal %s %s + %s equal %s 
#>  "1 + 1 equal 2"  "2 + 2 equal 4"
```

Comment: The use of `eval(parse()` seems like overkill here, and dangerous unless you trust the contents of `df`. Consider `df$arguments <- "{system('do-bad-stuff'); 1}"`

Comment: This doesn't work with a current (its now nearly 2024) version of dplyr, returning "2+2 equal 4" for both lines.

Comment: Thank you both for your input – much appreciated! It's great that we're all committed to keeping Stack Overflow solutions as clean as possible. :-) The code was quite old and definitely needed some polishing up. I've now updated my solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you mind taking another look and reconsidering your vote? I believe the updates address the issues raised. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

The `words` column is well suited for `sprintf`. Try the following :

```
df$combined <- apply(df, 1, function(x) do.call(sprintf, 
                       c(as.list(strsplit(x[2], ',')[[1]]), fmt = x[[1]])))
df

#             words arguments      combined
#1 %s + %s equal %s     1,1,2 1 + 1 equal 2
#2 %s + %s equal %s     2,2,4 2 + 2 equal 4
```

We split the `arguments` values on `","`, use `do.call` to pass them as separate arguments of `sprintf` and create the `combined` string. `x[2]` in `apply` refers to `arguments` column whereas `x[1]` is for `words` column.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Ronak's solution but using some `data.table` and `purrr` for concision:

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

df$combind <- map_chr(
  seq_len(nrow(df)), 
  ~do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = df$words[.], tstrsplit(df$arguments[.], ",")))
)

#              words arguments       combind
# 1 %s + %s equal %s     1,1,2 1 + 1 equal 2
# 2 %s + %s equal %s     2,2,4 2 + 2 equal 4
```